# Chinese frequency counter text analyser

Tags: mandarin

Can you recommend tool where I can import text and get result list with words according their frequency in text.
Aim to import Chinese subtitles learn most frequent words and then watch movie.

Comment: This question seems more fitting for http://stackoverflow.com/, as it is a question more about technology than Chinese specific

Comment: nop... It has nothing to do with programming.
Such tools exist I am sure. f.e. Chinese Toolbox 13 has similar tool. But I prefer free and online.

Comment: @Growler it's not fitting for Stackoverflow because OP is asking for a tool. It will get closed as off-topic

Comment: I know `xunsearch` provides a good engine for Chinese analyses, but it seems they don't provide a formal website to do that, you need to call their api by yourself. Anyway, they have a [demo](http://www.xunsearch.com/scws/demo/v4.php) that may meet your requirement -- just paste your text in the large text box, tick the check box before 只看统计, modify the number 10 after it to list more results (it even provides a text box for you to input what word class you want to exclude, `~v` means "exclude verbs"), and then click "submit". You may have a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boris, try this one: http://www.zhongguosou.com/zonghe/cipintongji.aspx

The UI is in Chinese, you may have to figure out how to use it.  I tried it myself. It is not user friendly. But this is the only one I found so far.

Comment: after few tries I got exactly what I need. Thanks!

Comment: Its hangs with error and not ordering (even with ordering option ON though)

Answer (score 0):

Python package "jieba" (结巴) should be a good alternative if you want to process a lot of text.
This package can split sentences into words and then what you need to do is only counting.